# Рестарт программы

Tags: c#, winforms

Есть первая форма `Input`.

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(sql.get());

try
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    List<Staff> staff = new List<Staff>();

    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT id, name, surname, patronymic FROM staff WHERE type = '1' AND disabled = '0'", sqlConnection);
    SqlDataReader sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader();

    while (sqlReader.Read())
    {
        staff.Add(new Staff {
            id = (int)sqlReader["id"],
            title = (string)sqlReader["surname"] + " " + (string)sqlReader["name"] + " " + sqlReader["patronymic"].ToString()
        });
    }

    comboBoxLogin.DataSource = staff;
    comboBoxLogin.DisplayMember = "title";
    comboBoxLogin.ValueMember = "id";

    sqlConnection.Close();
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    applog.write(err);

    DialogResult error = MessageBox.Show("Получить список администраторов не удалось, проверьте настройки подключения MS SQL Server. Открыть настройки MS SQL?", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    if (error == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        Form setting = new setting();
        setting.Owner = this;
        setting.Show();
    }

    if (error == DialogResult.No)
        Application.Exit();
}
```

Если к БД не получилось подключится, то открываем настройки. После того, как форму настроек закрыли нужно перезапустить программу.

Делаю так:

```
private void setting_Closed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Application.Restart();
}
```

Но если человек ввел настройки и опять не верные, то программа по каким-то причинам открывает два сообщения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Можете объяснить почему так происходит?

Comment: А зачем вам перезапускать программу? Почему бы просто не вызвать основную логику как функцию?

Comment: @Vlad вынес запрос к БД в отдельную функцию, при закрытии формы настройки вызываю функцию и всё равно два сообщения.

Comment: Ну поставьте breakpoint на открытие диалога и посмотрите, какими путями в туда приходите.

Comment: @VlaD, я понял в чём проблема. Такой вопрос возник: я так понимаю, что Closed вызывается после закрытия формы. Но если в Closed положить MessageBox, то форма не закрывается. Это так и должно быть?

Comment: После того как `MessageBox` закрыт, то и форма закроется.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а как закрыть форму и после открыть MessageBox?

Comment: Нужно делать это уровнем выше. Если текущая форма дочерняя, то `MessageBox` открывать в родительской. А если эта форма главная, то смотрите метод `Main` в классе `Program` (файл `Program.cs`): показывайте сообщение после `Application.Run`.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Форма настройки закрывается и уже в родительской открывается MessageBox, но настройки всё равно не закрываются, пока не закрою MessageBox.

Comment: `Application.Restart` сперва закрывает все формы, потом заново запускает приложение. Соответственно, при закрытии формы вызывается событие `FormClosed`. В общем, где-то ошибка в логике программы.

Comment: Всё всем спасибо. Логику плохо продумал.